# Filter by Multi Value Parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I need to filter my report( in the report itself not in the database side) based on multivalue paramater

I tried

```
Fields!MyField.Value IN Parameters!MyParm.Value

Fields!MyField.Value IN Join(Parameters!MyParm.Value, ",")

Fields!MyField.Value = Parameters!MyParm.Value

Fields!MyField.Value = Join(Parameters!MyParm.Value, ",")

Fields!MyField.Value LIKE Parameters!MyParm.Value

Fields!MyField.Value LIKE Join(Parameters!MyParm.Value, ",")
```

non works

How to do that?!

in the filter screen there is IN 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

","+join(Parameters!ParamNameHere.Value,",")  like "*,"+cstr(Fields!myValue.Value)+",*"

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options. I do think the easiest is so close to one of yours:

```
Fields!MyField.Value IN (@ParamNameHere)
```

See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2866/sql-server-reporting-services-using-multivalue-parameters/

Comment: i dont want to filter in the database side, i want to filter in the report side

Comment: this is on the report side.  Did your replace your parameter name into the param in the IN clause?

Comment: The details in the link fixed it for me. By default the filter Value changed to an expression referencing the first element of the parameter list (ie there was a (0) on the end. Just remove the (0) and the value will now be displayed as [@paramname] rather than <<Expr>> and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

If its not working you can try to build the filter a bit different. Add the following filter. Just replace the `Values` with your parameter values:

```
'Expression
=Fields!MyField.Value = "Value1" Or Fields!MyField.Value = "Value2"
'Format
Boolean
'Value
True
```

Now it displays just `Value1` and `Value2` in the tablix